# trigger a jquery effect when you scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I'm back with another question. I'm using the code below to add a bouncing effect to a div on my site. It works fine right now but the div has to be clicked in order for the effect to start. I would like to modify it so that when the user is scrolling down the page and reaches that section it triggers the effect automatically. How can I modify the code below to trigger the effect when the user scroll's down and reaches that section of the site?

Here is the code I' using

```
$(".servi-block").click(function () {
    doBounce($(this), 2, '10px', 150);
});

function doBounce(element, times, distance, speed) {
    for (i = 0; i < times; i++) {
        element.animate({
            marginTop: '-=' + distance
        }, speed)
            .animate({
            marginTop: '+=' + distance
        }, speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

```
$( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
  $( "#log" ).append( "<div>Handler for .scroll() called.</div>" );
});
```

Also utilize this

```
$('#target').on("mousewheel", function() {
    alert($(document).scrollTop());
});
```

Those two together should get you the ability to figure out you are scrolling, and when you reach position X, do something.

EDITED

Let's go at it this way -

```
var targetPos = "500px";

$( document ).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() == targetPos) {
    doBounce($(this), 2, '10px', 150);
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that's exactly what I'm looking for. I need it so that when the user scroll's down let's say 500px the effect starts automatically. It only needs to happen once not every time the user scroll's. Can that be accomplished with the examples you provided?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(event){
    isElementVisible = inViewport($(".servi-block"));
    if(isElementVisible)
    { 
        doBounce($(this), 2, '10px', 150); 
    }   
});


function inViewport (el) 
{
    var r, html;
    if ( !el || 1 !== el.nodeType ) { return false; }
    html = document.documentElement;
    r = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return ( !!r 
      && r.bottom >= 0 
      && r.right >= 0 
      && r.top <= html.clientHeight 
      && r.left <= html.clientWidth 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check to see when the element comes into view by taking the element's offset and subtracting that element's parent height and scrollTop value.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        var offset  = $('.element').offset().top,
            scroll  = $(document).scrollTop(),
            height  = $(document).height(),
            inViewDown = ((offset - scroll - height) <= 0) ? true : false;
        if (inViewDown) {
            // Do some stuff
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ughEe/